# Solr 7.2.1 Could not load driver

Tags: java, jdbc, solr

I am trying to get Solr to connect to a DB.

- Mac OS 10.13.3
- Java version "9.0.4"
- Solr 7.2.1

This is the error:

```
Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Processing Document # 1
```

My data-config.xml:

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource
                name="mysqltest"
                type="JdbcDataSource"
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product"
                user="solr"
                password="xxx"/>
        <document>
                <entity name="id"  dataSource="mysqltest" query="select *  from products">
                        <field column="id" name="id"/>
                        <field column="name" name="name"/>
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

solrconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
 <luceneMatchVersion>7.2.1</luceneMatchVersion>
 <lib dir="./lib" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />

<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I did several variations of the line:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\.jar" />
```

I tried absolut path, regex using *regex=".*.jar"*, without the backslash in the name of the connector.

The mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar is at the correct location.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the server startup log show it loading the mysql jar file?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Turning on startup logging showed the real problem. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also please post the log output? There seems to be a slash missing just before contrib in your lib directory, it should be like this:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/dataimporthandler/lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.11\.jar" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Turning on startup logging showed the real issue, the configs are correct.